# how to test angularjs app with angularjs e2e with multiple inputs with same ng-model

Tags: javascript, testing, angularjs, angularjs-e2e

in our program we have a directive that occurs multiple times with an input field. Our code looks something like this

```
<li>
    <label>AMI</label>
    <div class="searchbox" searchbox="" filter="search.ami">
        <form ng-submit="doFilter()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <input class="span12 ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text" placeholder="" ng-model="filter">        
        </form>    
    </div>
</li>

<li>
    <label>Username</label>
    <div class="searchbox" searchbox="" filter="search.username">
            <form ng-submit="doFilter()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
               <input class="span12 ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text" placeholder="" ng-model="filter">    
            </form>    
    </div>
</li>
```

now using the angular e2e test it says use the "input(name).enter(value)" to input, where the name is the ng-model. If i do this and say "input('filter').enter('foo')" both input fields will get inputted. I can't figure out how to just input one field at a time. How would you do so.

Comment: That's correct, because even you type manually, when you type in one input, the other input also be populated. Can you try that? It looks they are in the same scope.

Comment: Each form is in it's own directive which has it's own scope. So typing in one will not type in another

Comment: Oh i see, I didn't see the `form` ...

Comment: I figured it out. i need to use using to focus the scope. example using('div[filter="search.username"]').input("filter").enter("foo");
using('div[filter="search.ami"]').input("filter").enter("bar")

Comment: Awesome, please post it as an answer and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. i need to use using to focus the scope. example

using('div[filter="search.username"]').input("filter").enter("foo");
using('div[filter="search.ami"]').input("filter").enter("bar")